# Render 10000 polylines to a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, firefox, leaflet, openstreetmap, polyline

What is the best way to render nearly 10000 polylines to a leaflet map? I need my map to be interactive(hover events). Currently I am using leaflet 1.0 beta with canvas renderer. There is no problem with Chrome but Firefox seems to be much slower at this number of polylines.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you're trying? What have you found out so far? "Best" is very subjective without any constraints.

Comment: Also, a jsfiddle would be better, if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a I can't show you the code. I load a geojson file (linestring and properties). For now, "best" means that the map is interactive and the rendering performance is better in browsers, mostly in Firefox.

Comment: what is the size of your geojson file?

Comment: The size of the file is about 5-6 mb.

Comment: convert your **geojson** file to **topojson** so your file size would reduce. then render topojson file instead of geojson. Hope it'd work

Comment: It is good, that the file size is reduced, but it didn't work. 
I tried the leaflet geojson-vt plugin, it is good, but the way I see it can not be interactive.

Comment: I am almost trying the exact same thing. Though i load my data from wkb (well-known binary) over a socket connection. I noticed that the new canvas renderer introduced in leaflet v1.0 does not kick in. I only get svg.g elements in my dom. Anyways have you tried the L_PREFER_CANVAS = true option mentioned in the docs? Does it work for you? Does it improve performance?

Comment: Sorry my previous comment contains an error, they removed L_PREFER_CANVAS global switch and added Map preferCanvas option instead in leaflet v1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is only appearing in firefox, it may be because Firefox seems not very good at rendering many many SVG. One solution that worked for me is to switch the renderer to Canvas.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  renderer: L.canvas()
});
```

I can report 10 000 markers and zones with hovers and tooltip working smoothly

[A link to the documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#canvas)

Comment: link to documentation changed, use this link: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#canvas